# Counting page views with Aerospike

Tags: bigdata, aerospike

In the last few days I haven't found any good schema for counting page views in time series using Aerospike.

My objective is to have a graph that I can filter by date with hour granularity, giving me the page counts.

In my investigation I believe a correct approach would be using a Large Stack. But how? Each stack would be an hour or a page hit?

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the llist which supports a filter. You can use the filter to filter for the desired date range (stored as integer). Each entry in the llist can be for an hour. However, it's probably not the best way to update the value in llist for every page hit. I suggest that you maintain a non-ldt bin (simple integer) in the same record which will be used as counter for the current hour. Once an hour is completed, you can move this value to the llist and reset the counter. This way the page hit counter for the hour will be fast. And you can do graphing based on llist

Answer (score 0):

Python client supports increment function to maintain counters. Please check your client.  You can use LSTACK for achieving time series and you can get the length of the stack (count) easily by getting the stack size using your client.